# The use of the android:value in metadata -- Android

Tags: android, android-studio, android-manifest, manifest

I am confused with the use of values in metadata. When I am giving the metadata of an activity, what does it do with the `android:value` I give it. What does this value do.

Example

```
`        <activity
            android:name=".SecondActivity"
            android:label="@string/activity2_name"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity">
            <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".SecondActivity" />
        </activity>`
```

Yes I have looked at the documentation for meta-data on https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/meta-data-element. The description

> The value assigned to the item.

Does not make sense to me. Can anyone please explain the use of the `android:value` in metadata to me or rules on what to data to give it.

Why does it give me errors when I do not have a value in the manifest such as. 
`Failed to finalize session : INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED:`... `<meta-data> requires an android:value or android:resource attribute`

NOTE: I am not looking for a answer specific to my code for that error/ question. Just a general answer if there is one.

Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

meta-data is a **name-value pair**, so the meaning of `android:value` is dependent on `android:name`. 
For your example:

```
<meta-data
   android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY" //the activity has a parent activity 
   android:value=".SecondActivity" //the parent activity name is SecondActivity
/>
```

and what's parent Activity and how to use it ,you could ref https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral#top_of_page

if you only provides `android:name` but no `android:value`, its pointless.

Comment: so I should make the value the directory of the parent activity?
Where do I find the syntax for referencing the parent activity? @navylover

Answer (score 0):

@navylover 's answer is correct and helpful however I wanted to expand on it by saying. The value of the parent activity can be found by doing **"package name"."application name"."activity name"**

These can be found under the build.gradle file. 
An example of what the code will look like is on: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.